# Failing to recognize both keywords

Tags: c#, regex

Let me know if I'm asking the question in a wrong way. Not sure if I'm approaching it from the right angle.

My regex looks like this.

```
^.+(ef?)|(mn?).+$
```

I'm trying to match line 2 and 4 in the text below.

> abcd
>   efgh
>   ijkl
>   mnop
>   qrst

As it seem, only the last one catches the editors eye. What am I missing?

I've tried to follow [some examples](http://www.alertsite.com/help/RegexMatching.html) for detecting e.g. "*ALPHA*" and "*BETA*" words but, apparently, I'm too ignorant of how it works.

Comment: As I know, `^.+` means that there is at least 1 symbol at start. But Neither `efgh` nor `mnop` contains anything before `ef` or `mn`.

Comment: @Epsilon There actually is. It just doesn't show. My bad. Pretend there's a character before that (or switch to star instead of plus).   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex engine would split the below regex into two parts.

```
^.+(ef?)|(mn?).+$

  Part 1| Part 2
```

At-first, part1 will be executed.

```
^.+(ef?)
```

`.+` ensures that there must be atleast a single character present before `e`, but there isn't. So it fails to match the second one. And fails for all the others because there isn't a character `e` present in the remaining strings.

`|` OR

Now the regex engine moves to the second part,

```
(mn?).+$
```

Matches the string which contains the letter `m`. `m` is present only in the fourth string. So it matches the `m` plus the following one or more characters because of `.+`.

The correct approach to match the 2 and 4th strings is:

```
^.*(ef?).*$|^.*(mn?).*$
```

**OR**

```
^.*(?:(ef?)|(mn?)).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW5qZ0/2)

Use `^.*(?:(ef?)|(mn?)).+$`, if there must be a character follows `e` and an optional `f` or `m` and an optional `n`

If you want to match the strings starts with `e` or `m`, then use the below regex.

```
^(ef?|mn?).+$
```

**Note:**

- `.*` matches any character zero  or more times.
- `.+` matches any character one or more times.

Comment: Awesome. That's the problem I've been missing! While your answer is technically correct, I suggest an edition showing the correct syntax. Just to avoid the suspicion (oh, so common thing around SO) that I'm BSing and making others do my work, I'll take the liberty to edit your reply. Feel free to correct if you're not satisfied with it. +1 for a nerdy level of exactness.

Comment: Yes, yes I did. Why do you ask?